# Nested Key Query in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

**Firebase Data Structure**

```
{
  "books": {
    "-KaKjMMw-WQltqxrGEmj": {
      "categories": {
        "cat1": true,
        "cat2": true
      },
      "author": "user1",
      "title": "event1"
    },
    "-KaKjMMw-WQltqxrGEmk": {
      "categories": {
        "cat1": true,
        "cat2": false
      },
      "author": "user1",
      "title": "event2"
    }
  }
}
```

**Query To find all books of a particular author**

```
FNode.testNode.child("books")
    .queryOrderedByChild("author")
    .queryEqualToValue("user1")
    .observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
}
```

**Question:**

I want to find all the **books** belonging to **cat1**. Couldn't figure out the query to do that.

Comment: Sorry updated the datastructure! Tweaked a bit to hide my original purpose of data by changing keys. Failed badly. My bad ! :D

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of hit and trial, finally got my answer.

For the above structure. If you want to find all the **books** belonging to **cat1** Here is the query for that:

```
FNode.testNode.child("books")
    .queryOrderedByChild("categories/cat1").queryEqualToValue(true)
    .observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
}
```

Note: **FNode.testNode** could be any node of type **FIRDatabaseReference**

**To Firebase Team:** Can you please include a sample of all possible firebase queries in data structures and put it alongside firebase docs. It's kind of hit-and-trial for us now.

Comment: This works, but means you'll need to [define an index in your Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) for each category. For a more maintainable solution, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: Sure thanx for the link.

Comment: Also what are the disadvantage of querying without putting indexes in database rules? Will it really be slow?

Comment: It will download all data to the client and filter client-side. If that doesn't sound scary, read it again. Or turn on 2G. :-)

Comment: So if I query on books node. And put queries like above, it will download all the data of books node and filter client side?